# Nx - How to build packages with version from the central package.json

Tags: package.json, nrwl-nx

My Nx workspace builds some packages, using `@nrwl/web:rollup` executor, which my pipeline then publishes using `npm pack`+`npm publish`. I want all packages to have the same version, managed centrally in to root package.json. However, the resulting package.json's only take their versions from the individual libs' package.json's:

```
package.json:    version: 1.2.3
libs/lib1/package.json:    version: 4.5.6
libs/lib2/package.json:    version: 7.8.9
(generated) dist/libs/lib1/package.json     <<<<< Nx generates version: 4.5.6, I want it to generate 1.2.3
(generated) dist/libs/lib1/package.json     <<<<< Nx generates version: 7.8.9, I want it to generate 1.2.3
```

## Research

- Tried to remove the versions from the separate package.json's completely. Result: The generated package.json's don't have versions either, and npm pack fails.
- The documentation of https://github.com/jscutlery/semver seems to suggest this is possible - that's how their "Synced mode" works.
- I've seen suggestions to use [semantic-release](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-release) ([example](https://github.com/arenglish/nx-semantic-release-demo)), but that seems overkill for my needs - just generate the package versions correctly.

Comment: i am facing similar issue - with `"generatePackageJson": true` with `@nx/webpack:webpack` it generates package.json but is always v 0.0.1 and does not take the version from the root package.json...